# Track Elementor form submissions as conversions in GA4

Tags: forms, google-tag-manager, elementor, google-analytics-4, conversion-tracking

I would really appreciate your help!

The company I work for has an **Elementor** website with **different forms on separate pages**. There is no Thank You Page with form submissions.

We want to track the various forms as individual conversions in GA4, but we don't want to track it based on page URL.

If anyone has any tips or resources they could point me to, it would be HIGHLY appreciated!

I tried tracking page URL, but we are afraid URL changes in the future, so we need a different solution please.

Comment: Is there any chance the website can add datalayer code when form submit success?

Comment: I am not familiar with Elementor but if the forms have unique IDs, then you can trigger events based on this. Baked into GTM is the FormID variable.

Answer (score 0):

Faced this same issue...problem on the elementor forms is there doesnt seem to be a default form success event picked up by GA4 on submission where there is no redirect and the likes (at least from what I could pick up).

Second issue is the submit button is a button with a span for the button text.  Tried setting an ID for the button and targeting that but clicks pick up the span and not the button where the ID is.

Partial solve managed to get to work is:

- On your elementor form set a unique button ID for the submit button (just done in the interface itself)
- Create a custom JS variable in GTM with the code below

  ```
  function() {
  var element = {{Click Element}};
  while(element) {
    if (element.id === 'your-form-button-id') {
      return true;
    }
    element = element.parentElement;
  }
  return false;}
  ```

-> Name the JS variable clearly as this will be what you target in the trigger setup

- Create a trigger
  Create a new Trigger of type "All Elements".
  Set it to fire on Some Clicks.
  Add a condition where you'll use the custom JavaScript variable created above and set it to equals true
- Link up your trigger to GA4 event.

Note: The issue I still have with the above is that the submit button click will still trigger even if a validation rule fails.  So this is more like 'form complete attempted' and not really a 100% form complete.

hope this helps.